# Git: Move specific files from one branch in one repository to another branch in another repository

Tags: git

We have 1000s of autocad drawing files in, let's say Repo A, Branch1. Also, it contains other files. We *pull* this repository and after some steps, they are pushed to Repo B, Branch 2. The cumulative size is around 2GB and it takes lot of time to pull Repo A and commit to Repo B.

My questions are
1. Is there a way to copy, not move, the latest commit in Repo A Branch1 to Repo B Branch 2, in a lesser span of time?
2. Would like to copy only the specific file types, not all the files.

Comment: So A and B are both remote? Are they in the same place? Are we talking internally hosted (shared drive, web server, TFS, something like that) or externally (GitHub, etc.)? How does the time break down between pull, steps to prepare the commit in B, add, commit, push (i.e. which step(s) would saving time be practical and matter)?

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume the files you are committing are of a binary type, then no, I don't believe there are any shortcuts from Git's perspective here.

A commit in Git is a defined unit and cannot be broken up...if it was broken up then it would need a new identifier (sha) since they are generated based on the content of the commit plus it's parent commit.

The only option I can think of would be to check in your files using some type of compression but that would be abstracted away from Git's perspective.

Also, Git may not be the best tool for this type of storage. While Git can handle binary files it is mostly tailored towards storing text files that can be efficiently diffed.

Answer (score 0):

If the host of repo B has access to the host of repo A, then you could set up a remote on B so that you could directly pull changes from A into B.